# Derivative of overloaded function

Tags: function-construction, calculus-and-analysis

I have sets of functions of material parameters where the first input argument denotes the material. Here's a simple version:

```
tf1["a", x_] = x^3;
tf1["b", x_] = x^4;
```

Now, I'd like to make a function which needs the derivative of `tf1` with respect to x. My goal is the following:

> myderivative["a",x]=3 x^2
>
> myderivative["b",x]=4 x^3

The way to implement this should be something like

```
myderivative[i_, x_] = Derivative[2][tf1[i, #] &][x]
myderivativeb[i_, x_] = Derivative[0, 2][tf1][i, x]
```

I even tried

```
tf2[i_] = tf1[i, #] &
myderivative2[i_, x_] = Derivative[2][tf2[i]][x]
```

But all of the variants return

```
(tf1^(0,2))[i,x]
```

I tried using `SetDelayed` (`:=`) in all of the above variants but this doesn't return anything else. Also, approaches with `D` or `[Esc] pd [Esc]` failed.

So how do I take the derivative of this overloaded function? It should also work with distinct numbers, e.g. I expect

> myderivative["a",2]=12

Comment: `der[i_, x_] := D[tf1[i, x], x]` worked for me?

Comment: If `tf1` has a first variable, you should define it as:  `tf1[myname_?String, x_]` and define the specific functions for `myname = "a"` and `"b"`.

Comment: @Pillsy perfect, this seems like the only combination I didn't try... (I was mostly trying pure functions as the argument). Thanks!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork this is unrelated to the derivative, but a short example would help me a lot. And maybe a hint why this is better than my way. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pillsy however, your solution doesn't work for `der["a",3]`, for example. There's an error "General::ivar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest doing the derivative and then substituting in a value. This can be done as follows:

```
der[i_, x_] :=
  D[tf1[i, \[FormalX]], \[FormalX]] /. \[FormalX] -> x;
```

Using a "formal" variable means you don't have to worry about it being defined in scope and screwing things up.

Comment: great! I tried substituting and `ReplaceAll` but not with the formal variable. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
tf1[myname_String, x_] := Which[myname == "a", x^3, myname == "b", x^4];

D[tf1["a", x], x]
```

(* 3 x^2 *)

```
D[tf1["b", x], x]
```

(* 4 x^3 *)

If you have a "default" function for all string variables not yet entered, then:

```
tf1[myname_String, x_] := 
  Which[myname == "a", x^3, myname == "b", x^4, True, Sin[x]];

D[ft1["c",x],x]
```

(* Cos[x] *)

Comment: since I have many string parameters "a", "b", "c", etc I wanted to save the time of explicitely deriving all of them but wanted to do it as stated in the question (variable `i`). This is not possible, again giving the error "General::ivar" when putting in values

Comment: What is a "question variable"?

Comment: you didn't see the paranthese. Basically, Pillsy's answer is what I was looking for, as it keeps the variable `i` in the derivative.